# JSON treats numbers as base64 golang

Tags: json, go

Trying to send query output to browser as JSON, but numbers are treated as Base64. Integers prints out correct.

```
 var rows *sqlx.Rows 
 enc := json.NewEncoder(w)

 rows, err = db.Queryx(query)
  for rows.Next() {
    results := make(map[string]interface{})
    err = rows.MapScan(results)
    if err := enc.Encode(results); err != nil{
       fmt.Fprintf(w,"%s\n", results)
    }
 }
```

The result from JSON is (id integer, qty numeric / float):

> {"ID":1,"QTY":"OC4wMA=="}
>
> {"ID":2,"QTY":"OC4wMA=="}

Without JSON encoding, the numeric column is treated correct as numbers.

**EDIT**

@mkopriva hope this answer helps:

**"if you provide the table definition so we can see how the column is defined, it would also help to see the SQL query so we can see how you're pulling the column from the db"**

```
"ID"  int4
"QTY" numeric 

SELECT * FROM table
```

**and it would also help if you provide the code and its output which you mentioned as "treating the columns correctly as numbers"**

```
var rows *sqlx.Rows 

rows, err = db.Queryx(query)
for rows.Next() {
  results := make(map[string]interface{})
  err = rows.MapScan(results)
  fmt.Fprintf(w,"%s\n", results)
}
```

Gives this result:

> map[ID:1 QTY:9.75]
>
> map[ID:2 QTY:7.00]

**"can you do fmt.Printf("%T", results["QTY"]) for us? It is highly doubtful that if "QTY" is truly an int or float that the json encoder would marshal it as a base64 string.**

without JSON this gives:

> []uint8
> []uint8

Comment: why not use struct if you already know the structure of your result returned and then send it to browser

Comment: I do not know the struct. SELECT * FROM table.

Comment: This means your DB drivers returns not numbers but rather slices of bytes, `[]byte`, and that's why they get marshaled to JSON base64-encoded. You have to figure out what the real DB's data type of these columns which contain what you think are numbers and then ask a more comprehensive question so that we could make educated guesses about what exactly is the mismatch between the database type and that of Go.

Comment: @kostix It IS stored as numeric in Postgresql and shown as numeric when not using JSON. So it could be the postgresql driver?

Comment: The [docs](https://godoc.org/github.com/lib/pq#hdr-Data_Types) tell you which types are treated as `[]byte`.

Comment: You are encoding a map[string]interface{}. You are literally telling the json encoder "I don't care about my types, as long as you encode an object. Do whatever you want otherwise". Define a struct with the field types you want and encode that.

Comment: The random json encoder takes very good care of all columns but numbers. Should I interpret this as Golang is one way street regarding numbers using map[string]interface{} together with JSON? No work around?

Comment: @sibert can you do `fmt.Printf("%T", results["QTY"])` for us? It is highly doubtful that if `"QTY"` is truly an `int` or `float` that the json encoder would marshal it as a base64 string. e.g. https://play.golang.org/p/2U1JAu79LX-

Comment: ... also it would help, @sibert , if you provide the table definition so we can see how the column is defined, it would also help to see the SQL query so we can see how you're pulling the column from the db, and it would also help if you provide the code and its output which you mentioned as "treating the columns correctly as numbers".

Comment: ... and last but not least, Go's json encoder is not random, its behaviour is very well [documented](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/).

Comment: @Peter wrote "I don't care about my types, as long as you encode an object. Do whatever you want otherwise". It seems random to me :-)

Comment: @sibert `[]uint8` is not an `int` nor a `float` in Go, it's a slice of unsigned 8 bit integers. In Go a `byte` is an alias for `uint8` so it shows that what you have in your map are not numbers but slices of bytes. That means that this has nothing, whatsoever, to do with the json encoder.

Comment: @sibert I would guess that the source of your confusion stems from the fact that you're using fmt to print the value and then based on the output you're guessing the types of values. Don't do that, fmt is a like a UI, it doesn't necessarily provide a complete and accurate representation of a value. On top of that you're using `%s` which just adds to the confusion because `%s` is intended to provide a *readable* output for strings *and byte slices*. https://play.golang.org/p/djM8JXpR_eA always use `%v` or even better `%#v` to get a little bit better idea of what a value's type might be.

Comment: @mkopriva So it IS a dead end street? Notable is that exact same query  and about the same code are used in php/JSON and working perfect. So go back to php is one option? I was hoping that Golang was THE tool.

Comment: @mkopriva "you're using fmt to print the value ".The odd thing is that I can comment out the fmt and it is giving the same result.

Comment: @sibert I'm not saying that fmt is the cause of your problem, but the cause of your confusion. By that I mean that just because fmt prints `1` it doesn't mean that the passed in value was an `int`.

Comment: ©mkopriva The "ID" shows int64 using %T, so I guess it is encoding of the integer correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After countless attempts, I found a solution that solves the problem by converting numbers to strings. Not ideal, but rather simple.

```
var rows *sql.Rows
rows, err = db.Query(query)
cols, _ := rows.Columns()
colnames, _ := rows.Columns()
vals := make([]interface{}, len(cols))

for i, _ := range cols {  //bytes to string
   vals[i] = &cols[i]
}

mymap := make(map[string]interface{})

for i, v := range vals {  //adding column names
  mymap[colnames[i]] = v
}

for rows.Next() {
   err = rows.Scan(vals...)
   json, _ := json.Marshal(mymap)
   fmt.Fprintf(w,"%s\n",json)
}
```

Feel free to downvote, but please do me the honour to explain why.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you're using `lib/pq`, the `QTY` value is being converted into a byte slice which is actually the *correct* type for the corresponding postgres `numeric` type. This is because a value of type `numeric` cannot be reliably fit into a `float64` without loosing precision and so it makes sense for the driver to choose to convert a postgres `numeric` value into a Go `[]byte` value.

See here: https://github.com/lib/pq/issues/648#issuecomment-322674708

You can, however, explicitly tell the driver that you need a float by passing a Go value of type `*float64` to the `Scan` family of methods and the driver will convert the `numeric` into a `float64`, losing precission in the process. But if you pass an `interface{}`, the driver will make the most appropriate choice and convert the value to a byte slice.

If you don't care about precision but you must to use `interface{}` as the arguemnt to `Scan`, you can change the table column's type from `numeric` to `float`, if you do that then the driver can safely make the choice to convert your column into a Go `float64`.

If you care about precision, but for some reason you have to use a map of interfaces, you can write a simple function that converts a known key's value in the map from a `[]byte` to a `string`, after that, when you pass the updated map to the json encoder you'll see that key's value being encoded as a normal string instead of base64.

```
func bytesToString(k string, m map[string]interface{}) {
    if b, ok := m[k].([]byte); ok {
        m[k] = string(b)
    }
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/Ekih0oLd4-L

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean @sibert.

Comment: Can I pass the whole row and convert bytestostring or do I have to pass each column to this func?

Comment: You would pass in a single instance of `map[string]interface{}`, for example the `results` variable from your code in the original question. And as the first argument you would pass in the name of the column which you want to convert, e.g. "QTY". Something like this: https://play.golang.org/p/oBuq4VKG1Gg This allows converting a single map value at a time, or a single row column at a time if we speak in db terms. But nothing stops you from implementing a similar function that takes a map and a variadic number of keys to convert multiple columns in a single call to the function.

Comment: Basically column level as I interpret it. The problem is that sometimes the column names are unknown, so it has to be triggered by the []uint8 instead. Possible?

Comment: It's possible if you're ok with the assumption that every `[]unit8` needs to be converted, that is, if you're sure that every column that gets converted to `[]uint8` by the driver is ok to be converted to a `string`. To do it, just `range` over the map's values, in the loop type assert each value as `[]uint8` and if assertion is successful convert the value to a `string`.

Comment: If I convert the []uint8 to string. How do I update the content (map / interface ?) with this string? Before I encode it and print it?

Comment: Just like you would if you would use the `bytesToString` function in the answer. E.g. `m[k] = string(b)`. These are Go basics and if you're unfamiliar with them you should consider taking the [Go tour](https://tour.golang.org/welcome/1).